# How to implement a ListView with the rest of an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to include a ListView into my main Activity. My java code for the main activity is as follows:
    public class StylbugActivity extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
private ListView x;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedinstanceState);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
    x = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_list_view);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    x.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

whereas my main.xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="what"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/testButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="test1"
    android:text="Button" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />



</LinearLayout>
```

However when I test my program out, it just breaks on me when I try to boot it. Can anyone help?

Comment: I did some testing and it turns out it crashes because of null pointer exception, as "x" turns out to be NULL

Comment: additionally, I realized that I didn't put setContentView(R.layout.main), which when I put in as the 2nd line of onCreate, x still returns NULL

Comment: Please update your post with `setContentView` and error cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you extend ListActivity instead of Activity it will work fine.  Because you are using setContentView(R.layout.main) then the ListView x is never initialized.  I dont know exactly what you are trying to accomplish overall, but this will make your ListView work.

```
public class ListExample extends ListActivity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedinstanceState);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

You will have to do some other work to make the TextView and Button from your xml to work in this set up.

You can also go the route that you are using, but you have to setContentView(R.layout.main) or you will continue to get a NPE.